# Почему undefined при вызове функции JS?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
function NextIdPost(type, idDialog){
    switch (type) {

       case 'messageChat':
          redis_cli.incr(type + ':' + idDialog, function( err, id ) { 
                return id;
          });

        break
    }
}

var id = NextIdPost('messageChat', idDialog);
            console.log(id); // undefined
```

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/207778/

Comment: А если так: 

var id; 
redis_cli.incr(type + ':' + idDialog, function( err, id ) { 
         id = id;
     });
break

return id;

Comment: не пркатит, redis_cli.incr - асинхронная, используйте callback.

Comment: Можете разъяснить. Т-е  redis_cli.incr выполняется одновременнно с NextIdPost

Comment: не одновременно, после того, как она выйдет. вам нужно постичь асинхронность, сейчас в ответе распишу.

Comment: @IOleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Асинхронные функции выполняются так:

```
function mainStreamIncrorrect() {
 var i=0; //это синхронный вызов,
 i=assyncFunc(1); //асинхронный, assyncFunc сразу вернет 
                     //какие-то данные, но не выполнит то что запрошено, см ниже
                     //такой вызов - не правильный

 console.log(i); //undefined
}// mainStrem закончен, после того, как закончится поток вызвавший функцию, запустится всё что стало в очередь, в данном случае callback

//эта функция асинхронно умножит аргумент на 2
function assyncFunc(data,callback) {
        process.nextTick(function() { //только в nodejs
              callback && callback(data*2); //очевидно, что этот момент наступит позже окончания вызвавшего потока.
        });
return; //вот undefined который вернется сразу после вызова
}
//вызовем правильно
function mainStream() {
    assyncFunc(1,outPut); //первый аргумент - данные для обработки
                          //второй аргумент - функция которая готова их принять.
    function outPut(i) { //вызовется изнутри асинхронной функции, когда данные будут обработаны.
      console.log(i);//2
    }
}
```

---

ваш случай:

```
function NextIdPost(type, idDialog,cb){
    switch (type) {

       case 'messageChat':
          redis_cli.incr(type + ':' + idDialog, function( err, id ) { 
                cb(id);
          });
          return;

        break
    }
    cb();// если не нашли - undefined.
}
var id;
NextIdPost('messageChat', idDialog,setId);
function setId(Id) {
            id=Id;
            console.log(id);
    }
```

Comment: контрольный вопрос - при таком вызове

    mainStream();
    mainStreamIncorrect();

что будет в консоли ?

Comment: 1, undefined, 1

Comment: откуда три значения ? (я поправил пример чтобы работал :) )